# Is There a Way to Have an Arraylist Element Equal to a Class Constructor?

Tags: java, class, oop, variables, arraylist

For an assignment on Arraylists, I am required to change the 1D array into an array list, meaning modifying the program from listName.length to listName.size(), etc.

I am having a problem with declaring my array list animals to a class method. I did this: `animals.get(x) = new Dog(name, age);` but I am getting an error where it says the left-hand side must be a variable. The same error is occurring on `new Cat(name, age);` and on `new Bird(name, age);`.

Now, I have tried creating a String variable and assigning to `animals.get(x)` and then assigning that variable to `new Dog(name,age)` which also does not work, as it wants me to change `new Dog(name, age)` to string (meaning change my variable name, lets say `String string`, to `Dog string`), and when I do that, I`m back at square one and it asks me to change my variable back to String.

```js
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class Database { 
 ArrayList<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>(); 
 Database (int s) { 
  animals.size(); 
 }//end of Database(s)

    boolean addAnimal (int type, String name, int age) {
     for (int x = 0; x < animals.size(); x++) {
      if (animals.get(x) == null) {
       if (type == 1) {
        animals.get(x) = new Dog(name, age);      
       }//end of if 
       else if (type == 2) {
        animals.get(x) = new Cat(name, age);  
       }//end of else if
        else {
                              animals.get(x) = new Bird(name, age);
        }//end of else
        return true;    
      }//end of outer if   
     }//end of for loop  
     return false;
    }//end of addAnimal(type, name, age)

 Animal removeAnimal (String name) {
  for (int x = 0; x < animals.size(); x++) {
   if (animals.get(x).equals(null)) {
    // If the spot in the array is null skip this index
   }//end of if
   else if (animals.get(x).equals(name)) {
    String found = animals.get(x); 
    animals.at(x) = null;
    System.out.print(found);
   }//end of else if
  }//end of for loop
  return null;
 }//end of removeAnimal(name)
}//end of class Database
```

Since I am modifying everything to fit array lists, I have to modify the method above as well when the user chooses to add an animal. There are three animals, Dog, Cat, and Bird, all of which have their own classes. I`m expecting the error'the left-hand side must be a variable' to disappear, and I`ve tried searching ways to fix it, but I can`t seem to find a solution similar to my problem.

EDIT UPDATE

I included the complete code for my Database class (the class that has the methods addAnimal and removeAnimal).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets be careful here, ArrayList's size method doesn't work like an array's length:

```
new Object[10].length; // returns 10

List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>(10);
list.size(); // returns 0

list.addAll(Collections.nCopies(10, null));
list.size(); // returns 10

new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(10, null)).size(); // returns 10
```

As you can see, ArrayLists don't store nulls by default, instead they simply don't store anything. That means there shouldn't be a need to loop through and finds nulls... You can simply add the value to the list.

```
boolean addAnimal(int type, String name, int age) {
    if (type == 1) {
        animals.add(new Dog(name, age));
    }
    else if (type == 2) {
        animals.add(new Cat(name, age));
    }
    else {
        animals.add(new Bird(name, age));
    }
    return true; // You can probably make this a void method now
}
```

P.S. I've seen in the comments your ArrayList is of type String ... Your animals aren't strings, so you can either convert them to strings using `new Dog(name, age).toString()`, or what I'd recommend is changing your ArrayList to be a common type (ie. `ArrayList<Animal> animals` or `ArrayList<Object> animals`).

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! i fixed the second part, but the first part '(new Object[10].length;...new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(10, null)).size();)' I am having a little problem. I included this part in my removeAnimal method, and the method returns null. So, when I run the program and choose to 'pick up' an animal (the method removeAnimal comes in handy for this), I enter the name of the animal and even if the animal exists, the program is printing out 'Animal/Pet not found :('

Comment: else if (answer == 2) {    
 System.out.println("What is the name of your pet?");
 name = input.next();
        Animal myPet = db.removeAnimal(name);
 if (myPet == null) {   
  System.out.println("Pet not found :(");     
 }//end of if

Comment: To find an animal by name you can return `animals.stream().filter(a -> a.getName().equals(name)).findAny().orElse(null)`

Answer (score 4):

According Java documentation of ArrayList ([ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)), you should use "add" function in order to insert a new element to the ArrayList, which means your code should look something like this:

```
boolean addAnimal (int type, String name, int age) {
    for (int x = 0; x < animals.size(); x++) {
        if (animals.get(x) == null) {
            if (type == 1) {
                animals.add(new Dog(name, age));                    
            }//end of if    
            else if (type == 2) {
                animals.add(new Cat(name, age));        
            }//end of else if
                else {
                          animals.add(new Bird(name, age));
                }//end of else
                return true;                
        }//end of outer if          
    }//end of for loop      
    return false;
}//end of addAnimal(type, name, age)
```

Note: I am assuming that the type of the variable "animals" is ArrayList when T is an interface of abstract class of Animal.

Hope i got the question right, let me know if it wasn't your intention.

**EDIT:**

Well, since your Dog and Cat classes are implementing Animal interface, the type of the ArayList should be:

```
ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
```

instead of:

```
ArrayList<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now, if your intention is just to add new objects to the ArrayList without any other logic (like removing duplicates), you would like to just check the type of the Object and decide what class you should create and add the ArrayList. Then, the code should look like this:

```
boolean addAnimal (int type, String name, int age) {
    switch(type){
    case 1:
        animals.add(new Dog(name, age));
        return true;
    case 2:
        animals.add(new Cat(name, age)); 
        return true;
    default:
        animals.add(new Bird(name, age));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Another **TIP**: I don't know about your overall task, but creating a Bird if the type isn't 1 or 2 might not be a good practice since it basically represents that "If an animal isn't a dog or a cat it must be a bird", which in most cases not a very good logic. So my tip is to give a Bird a certain type as well (like 3) and if the type is not 1, 2 or 3 You can alert that the type dosen't exists or something like that.
So i would use the "default" as a default:

```
boolean addAnimal (int type, String name, int age) {
    switch(type){
    case 1:
        animals.add(new Dog(name, age));
        return true;
    case 2:
        animals.add(new Cat(name, age)); 
        return true;
    case 3:
        animals.add(new Bird(name, age));
        return true;
    default:
        System.out.println("This type does not exists"); // Or some other operation
    }
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

By the way, since "add" can return boolean value if the addition succeed or not, the code can be more elegant:

```
boolean addAnimal (int type, String name, int age) {
    switch(type){
        case 1: return animals.add(new Dog(name, age));
        case 2: return animals.add(new Cat(name, age)); 
        case 3: return animals.add(new Bird(name, age));
        default: System.out.println("This type does not exists"); // Or some other operation
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have tried this, but it is underlining the 'add' part and prompting me to change it to 'addAll...()' which I did. Another red line appears under addAll, and the program prompts me to either 'Cast an argument new Cat(name, age) to (Collection<? extends String>). I then see a yellow line, and then it tells to add @SuppressWarnings...

Comment: Yes, the type of variable for 'animals' is ArrayList<String>

Comment: I have included the complete code for the Database class, the class that adds and removes an animal (choice can be made in the main method)

Comment: Well, since Dog and Cat are implementing interface Animal, the type of the ArrayList should be Animal:
'ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();'
instead of:
'ArrayList<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();'
Plus, as Adam said in another answer, you'll need to remove the for loop since ArrayList initialize without any objects, therefore the size=0.

Answer (score 3):

"=" assigns the value on its right to the variable on its left. in your example you want to assign object to object instead of object to variable (animals.get(x) returns object).

Proper way for edit ArrayList element is (as mentioned @Krzysztof Arłasik) method `set(int,Object)`.

In your example:

```
boolean addAnimal (int type, String name, int age) {
    for (int x = 0; x < animals.size(); x++) {
        if (animals.get(x) == null) {
            if (type == 1) {
                animals.set(x,new Dog(name, age));                  
            }//end of if    
            else if (type == 2) {
                animals.set(x,new Cat(name, age));      
            }//end of else if
            else {
                      animals.set(x,new Bird(name, age));
            }//end of else
            return true;                
        }//end of outer if          
    }//end of for loop      
    return false;
}//end of addAnimal(type, name, age)
```

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. I tried this just now. However, it is underlining the 'set' part in red, and the error reads: "The method set(int, String) in the type ArrayList<String> is not applicable for the arguments (int, Bird)"

Comment: I have included the rest of the code for my Database class. It`s the class that adds and removes an animal (this choice can be made in the main method)

Comment: It's because your `ArrayList` is declared as `ArrayList<String>`. You should for example create abstract class or interface `Animal`, your animals classes (Dog,Cat,Bird) should extend/implement `Animal` and your `ArrayList` should be declared as `ArrayList<Animal>`

Comment: Or if you dont want to create another level of abstraction you can create. 'ArrayList<Object>' but usually it's bad idea because it can produce runtime exceltions

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` has method [set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set-int-E-), which you should use in your case.

For example:

```
animals.set(x, new Dog(name, age));
```

Comment: I tried this, but I am getting an error at 'set'. The error read: "The method set(int, String) in the type ArrayList<String> is not applicable for the arguments (int, Bird)". Thank you for your help though (:

Comment: Of course. But for what class? Animal class? (this class just creates variables: names and ages and has getters and setters for it) Launcher class? (this class has the main method) Database class? (this class creates the array list for animals, adds and removes an animal (three animals: Dog, Cat, Bird, each has their own classes where they have methods that make noises or do actions for these animals))

Comment: Atlasik Like you said, I have edited my question and included the rest of my code for the Database class which is the class that adds and removes an animal (choice can be made in the main method)